# shutdown system saftly glassfish and apache

Tags: apache, glassfish

I have two server `glassfish` and `apache`, when maintaining the sysytem i want to make sur that i have no connecting client, or stop receiving new clients and wait for the current clients until they finish theire tasks then shutdown the system. how can i do this from `linux servers` ?

I used `netstat -nap | grep :80` but since i have actife connection between glassfish and apache i dont know how to determine the exact number of connected clients.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1825/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1703/httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume apache listens on port 80 and glassfish on port 8080. You can go with your command or you can use this:

```
netstat -nat | grep :80 | grep EST
```

That will output the established connections on port 80 and port 8080 (if there are any).

If you want real-time stats you could use this:

```
netstat -ntapc | grep :80 | grep EST
```

**-c** reloads the output every second